# stradus jquery plugin parameter links

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question i'm using stradus jquery player to play soundcloud content from my site it has different parameters one of them is link

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $stratus({
      auto_play: true,
      download: false,
      links: 'http://soundcloud.com/qotsa',
      random: true
    });
  });
```

but i wan't to get the soundoudlinks from my database with php and load them in links i tried everything but i always get a Syntax Excpected error , anybody an idea how to make the string with php?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.stratus({
      links: <?php echo(implode("','", $soundcloudsurl)); ?>

    });
  });
</script>
```

this is my code!

Comment: Show your code which prints a link for a plugin.

Comment: i added my code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose below code should work (if everything is ok with urls in array). Just put `'` around `<?php ... ?>` and remove it from first parameter of implode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.stratus({
      links: '<?php echo(implode(",", $soundcloudsurl)); ?>'

    });
  });
</script>
```

As far as I understand their docs, links should be a string with urls separated with comma.